# How do I choose what source files get compiled for each platform?

Tags: c++, makefile, cross-platform

Say I have a file structure like:

- **win32/**  *Something.cpp*
- **linux/**  *Something.cpp*
- Something.h
- main.cpp

How would I be able to implement:

```
UNAME = $(shell uname -s)

ifeq ($(UNAME), Linux)
    OS = linux
else
    OS = win32
endif

all:
    g++ ?????
```

I've been at a loss for around an hour now. I've never attempted cross platform makefiles so I usually just let the IDE handle it but now I need to create it because the IDE isn't really cut out for cross platform projects.

PS: Something.h is just a class definition/prototype and the linux/ and win32/ source files are just providing a method for that class. Problem is that I get a compilation error saying the class is already declared if both exist without some form of build target or whatever.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi platform Makefiles are an advanced topic. You might want to take a look at scons. Anyway, here is how you could make your case work:

Build your list of sources depending on the `$(UNAME)`:

```
UNAME = $(shell uname -s)
TARGET = myprogam
SRC_COMMON = main.cpp

ifeq ($(UNAME), Linux)
    SRC_OS = $(wildcard linux/*.cpp)
else
    SRC_OS = $(wildcard win32/*.cpp)
endif

SRC = $(SRC_COMMON) $(SRC_OS)
OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
```

Comment: How would I go about actually selecting a directory of each source file though? Sorry, I'm new to this makefile and to be honest, it seems confusing as hell.